# Create a combobox in qgis plugin to input text (string)

Tags: qgis, python, combo-box

I'm developing a plugin in QGIS, with a dialog box where I want to insert text (string) and send to web service soap.

I don't found much on the internet.

Except this code that i have adapted:

```
qid = QInputDialog()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
input, ok = QInputDialog.getText( qid, "Enter Date", "Enter text", QLineEdit.Normal, "Date" + "," + "Text")
if ok:
    Date = input.split( "," )[ 0 ]
    print Date
    Name = input.split( "," )[ 1 ]
    print Name
```

But this code don't work in the combobox that i want.

I create this ComboBox in QCreator:

[image: combobox]

Can someone help me to adapt the code to this combobox?

Comment: Did make it a widget? Try to build a QtDialog with that widget a provide a run method to get a result from that dialog.

Comment: I make the combobox in QTCreator. My difficult is to give an action to the send button. When i click in the button it don't does nothing.

Comment: The logic off your plugin must be programmed in python! Did you read the cookbook? https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html

Comment: Yes, i read the book. This is not my first plugin in python to Qgis. I develop other plugin, but don't have combobox. My difficulty is to give  an action to the send button.